# Accessing local variables from another function another function without returning Python

Tags: python, function, variables, localization, return

Is there a way to access the contents of `function_.py`'s `func()` functions local variables `a,b,c...s` from `main.py` wikthout having to return the function on main, being like `a,b...s = main()`. If so how would I be able to do it.

function_.py:

```
func():

   a = 5
   b = 4
   c = 11
   k = 55
   d = 99
   s = 66
```

Main.py

```
import function_

def main():
   func()
   print(a, b, c, d, k, d, s)
main()
```

Comment: No, you cannot do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do what you're pretending to. I suggest to create a class instead a function, this way:

##### File 2:

```
class SecondFile(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
        self.d = 4
        self.e = 5
```

##### File 1:

```
from second import SecondFile

def main():
    x = SecondFile()
    print(x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d, x.e)
        
main()
```

##### Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are alive only inside the function where you create them. One of ways is setting global variables in function_.py

function_.py

```py
a = 0
b = 0
# ...
func():
   global a, b
   a = 5
   b = 4
```

main.py

```py
from function_ import a, b

x = a
y = b
```